# TypeError: tls.connect is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tls1.2, nodemailer

I keep getting this issue tls.connect is not a function. 
I am using nodemailer with my Reactjs and Nextjs application.

```
sendmail.js?71c0a4a:33 Error: TypeError: tls.connect is not a function
at SMTPConnection.connect (index.js?49b6f52:228)
at getSocket (index.js?55ebb9c:234)
at setImmediate (index.js?55ebb9c:70)
at run (setImmediate.js?d2412a6:40)
at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js?d2412a6:69)
at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js?d2412a6:109)
```

The weird part is if I run the script in the console it will work, but running though the browser I get the tls.connect is not a function error.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    secure: false, 
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: '',
        pass: ''
    },
});

class mail {

    options (to, text, subject, html) {
        console.log(to)
        var mailOptions = {
            from: '', 
            to: to, 
            subject: subject, 
            text: text, 
            html: html 
            }
        return(mailOptions);
    }

    sendMail(mailOptions) {
        console.log(mailOptions)

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.error('Error:', error);
            }
            console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
        });
    }
}

export default mail;
```

Comment: You can't run that code in the browser, as it requires being able to set up generic TCP connections (which you can't in a browser). You need to make sure that code is run server-side only.

Comment: Thanks for replying @robertklep I have to make a call to the mail class to send emails on demand. Would I use the  'process.browser' to make sure that it isn't trying to render on the client side?

Comment: You probably want to set up a [custom server](https://zeit.co/blog/next2#programmatic-api) to implement an API that you can call from the frontend to send e-mails.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're using nodemailer inside a bundler, on Client Side, 
NodeMailer should only be used at ServerSide.

This issue is environmental and also be aware that even if that was working, you would be exposing that google account and password by using it at client side.

Consider creating a serverside nodejs api to send your emails

[issue](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/738)